# AngularJS Multiple Module Failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, smart-table

I am trying to add the module 'smart-table' to my module. I have followed the instruction on the website (http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) and used bower install angular-smart-table to install smart table.

```
angular.module("App", ['ngRoute','ui-leaflet'])
```

When I add 'smart-table' to the above code:

```
angular.module("App", ['ngRoute','ui-leaflet','smart-table'])
```

My app no longer works. I have spent hours trying different solutions including and cannot figure out why the modules will not work together.

edit:

This is from my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js"></script>
```

And from my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-sample",
  "authors": [
    ""
  ],
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-lock": "10.2.2",
    "angular-jwt": ">= 0.1.3",
    "angular-lock": "~1.0.2",
    "a0-angular-storage": "0.0.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "angular-smart-table": "2.1.8"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: check errors in console.. you might have miss to include js file reference

Comment: missing the js file reference in my html code or somewhere else?

Comment: " 
check errors in console.. you might have miss to include js file reference" as @PankajParkar said + post your index file, bower.json and commands you used to install it.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have to do include in your html file

```
<script src="smart-table.js"></script>
```

then add to your module

```
var app = angular.module('app',['smart-table']);
```